# React : Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS . I want to call this function when User click on but in meantime it give me error `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` Could someone please help me how to solve this problem 
Thanks

**Code**

```
getSortedData =() => {
    let newSort = 'name asc';
    if (this.state.sorteData === newSort) 'name desc';

    this.setState({sortedData: newSort}, () => {
        this.getData();
    })
}
```

Comment: You forgot to assign to variable. `if (this.state.sorteData === newSort) newSort = 'name desc';`

Comment: Actually , I want to toggle the order . If User click on first time I want to update it with name `asc` , if user click second time I want to update with name `desc`

Comment: This error message comes from a linter, right? It's not a syntax error, the code is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Think your issue is this line `if (this.state.sorteData === newSort) 'name desc';` where there is an arbitrary string.

If you mean to assign that to new sort, trying adding this in:

```
if (this.state.sorteData === newSort) {
 newSort = 'name desc';
}
```

Comment: Actually , I want to toggle the order . If User click on first time I want to update it with `name asc` , if user click second time I want to update with `name desc`

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as the other answers but hopefully helps you see:

```
let newSort = (this.state.sorteData === newSort) ? 'name desc' : 'name asc';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle the order try this approach.

```
getSortedData = () => {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        sortedAscending: !prevState.sortedAscending
    }), () => {
        this.getData();
    });
}

getData = () => {
  const sorting = this.state.sortedAscending ? 'name asc' : 'name desc'
  // do your stuff
}
```